# Where does Black and White keep savegames?

Tags: black-and-white

I'm looking at moving an old Black & White savegame off an old hard drive to my current machine, but I can't figure out where it stores saves. They're not in My Games or the install folder, that I can see. Where are Black and White savegames kept?

Comment: Wait, what? Were you using a computer or something?

Comment: @TheUgly Not Pokemon. This is a different game. :)

Comment: The edit history on the title is kinda hilarious...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Studoku's answer is correct as far as older Windows versions are concerned (XP and earlier).

For Vista and later, if you installed to the default location and did not run the game as administrator, you will likely need to look in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\VirtualStore`, then navigate to the subfolder that corresponds to your Black & White installation, e.g. `%LOCALAPPDATA%\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Lionhead Studios\Black & White\Profiles`.

By default, `%LOCALAPPDATA%` is `C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Local`; but just typing it into Explorer should open the correct folder.

On a related note, I always create my own top-level folder for games (`C:\Games`). A lot of these older titles try to save stuff in the application directory, which has actually been a bad practice for many years now - but a lot of game developers were very slow to stop doing that, so a lot of them end up with their stuff in the VirtualStore, thanks to the redirection performed by Windows. Using a custom top-level folder bypasses this problem, since that will have all the permissions it needs to write with the normal user account.

Comment: I usually do that now, but that sadly doesn't make my past self smarter. New savegame, here I come.

Answer (score 2):

They're stored in the profiles folder in the folder where you installed the game. Typically this would be `C:/Program files (x86)/Lionhead Studios/Black & White/Profiles`.

You'll also need to copy over your creature from /scripts/creaturemind

Comment: To add to this, [PC Gaming Wiki](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Black_and_White) states that Black and White should be "installed outside Program Files on Windows Vista and newer to avoid saving issues (see [Can't save the game](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Black_and_White#Can.27t_save_the_game))".

Comment: For Vista and later, if you installed to the default location and did *not* run the game as administrator, you will likely need to look in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\VirtualStore`, then navigate to the subfolder that corresponds to your Black & White installation, e.g. `%LOCALAPPDATA%\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Lionhead Studios\Black & White\Profiles`. (By default, %LOCALAPPDATA% is C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Local; but just typing it into Explorer should open the correct folder).

Comment: @MichaelMadsen Ohhhh… nuts. The backup I have doesn't include the virtual store from that system. Well, I probably sucked at this game before anyway—I seem to recall that I mis-trained my tiger to be a constipated coward, so I guess it's just as well I have to start over.

Comment: @MichaelMadsen I want to accept that comment as the answer, since it solved/illuminated the problem. :/